# "error while loading shared libraries: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory" when running TRTorch sample

Tags: pytorch, tensorrt, libtorch

I'm trying to compile my pytorch model with TRTorch engine.
I've installed TRTorch according to [this](https://nvidia.github.io/TRTorch/tutorials/installation.html) link. 
When the sample code is run (with the below command from this [link](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TRTorch/tree/master/cpp/trtorchexec)) the given error arise:

`sudo bazel run //cpp/trtorchexec -- $(realpath /home/TRTorch/tests/modules/alexnet_scripted.jit.pt) "(1,3,227,227)"`

> error while loading shared libraries: libnvinfer.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Also, the *LD_LIBRARY_PATH* is set correctly.

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/TensorRT/TensorRT-7.0.0.11/lib

More info:

> TRTorch: latest version (python package and binary) 
> TensorRT: 7.0.0.11 
> Pytorch: 1.5.1 
> CUDA: 10.2 
> Python: 3.6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this question in TRTorch github and fixed it using:

`sudo LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/TensorRT/TensorRT-7.0.0.11/lib bazel run //cpp/trtorchexec $(realpath tests/models/alexnet_traced.jit.pt) "(32 3 227 227)"`

The issue is available [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/TRTorch/issues/157).